# How to set Encoding.Default for .NET app?

Tags: .net, docker, encoding

I have a problem with running the app in two different environments: local and inside docker container.
The problem is the fact, that `Encoding.Default` is used in the app. `Encoding.Default` on the local machine returns cp1252, and inside docker container it returns utf-8.

I know, it's a very bad practice to use `Encoding.Default`, and it will be fixed in future, but I have no rights to change it now. All I have to do right now is to run the app correctly inside the docker with it current state.

As far as I know, `Encoding.Default` returns system locale, so I need to change system locale of docker image to something, which uses cp1252. But I didn't find the way, how to do this.

I've used `chcp` command before running the app - `Encoding.Default` still returns utf-8.
I've tried `Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-us` in powershell, but still get utf-8 as a default encoding.

The app is .NET Framework 4.7 console app. The docker image is [.NET Framework Runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-runtime/), which is based on Windows Server 2019 I suppose.

How to change the system settings of it in cmd/powershell to force `Encoding.Default` to return cp1252 instead of utf-8?

**EDIT:**
`Encoding.Default` is using GetACP() windows native function, and inside docker container it always returns 65001. chcp command doesn't help:

```
PS C:\> $Signature = @"
>> [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] public static extern int GetACP();
>> "@
PS C:\> $acpGetter =  Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru
PS C:\> $acpGetter::GetACP()
65001
PS C:\> chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252
PS C:\> $acpGetter::GetACP()
65001
```

Comment: just to add to your pain (that's what you wanted, right?) : in .NET Core (not sure if it matters per version), `Encoding.Default` is **always** UTF-8; doesn't help, but probably important to know about; I *thought* .NET Framework always returned a code-page, so; are you sure you aren't testing .NET Core if you're seeing UTF8? If I try NET47 or NET48 locally (windows), I see iso-8859-1, not UTF8 (and if I switch to .NET Core: UTF8)

Comment: Yeah, I know about .NET Core behavior on this matter. The app is definitely targeted to .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: so, checking the IL, NETFX will return UTF8 if (and only if) `GetACP` returns 65001; presumably, then, you need to set the system locale to 65001 - perhaps use https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4677 to test it somewhere and see what value it sets it to, in terms of `Set-WinSystemLocale` ? but: there's also things that suggest this isn't going to end well: https://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7

Comment: I've checked, GetACP() always returns 65001 in my case. WTF.

Comment: well, I can't answer the underlying question, but: we're a step further in understanding the scenario, at least!

Comment: maybe `chcp 65001` / `chcp 1252` ? (although apparently I'm using 850)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Checked it with following snippet in powershell inside docker container: https://pastebin.com/26vWKD3T